# copy model folder using Rest API

Tags: rest, alfresco

I'm working with Alfresco Community edition , and i wanna Copy a folder using the Api only because i don't have access to js CMIS ,  i found so Url to post my Data to but i'm always blocked by an http 401 error , even though my ticket is valide and i also add to the header the authorisation data. 
i have both the source folder nodRef :
this is the model folder :

```
workspace://SpacesStore/aeeaca0a-89bf-4294-8506-315ecd7d18f2
```

and the destination parent Id (where the copied folder should be :

```
workspace://SpacesStore/48fcc674-fe08-4802-963b-ca8e2ccd1a62
```

any help from you guys is appreciated . Thank you

 from the documentation i do a POST to this adress `/alfresco/s/slingshot/doclib/action/copy-to/node/{store_type}/{store_id}` 
in the header i need `content-type:application/json` and `authorization : basic 'base64_encode(ROLE_TICKET:$ticket'`

Comment: Which REST call do you make exactly? Which HTTP headers do you set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. [Authorization](https://github.com/Alfresco/community-edition/blob/master/projects/remote-api/source/java/org/alfresco/rest/api/impl/AuthenticationsImpl.java), you can use:

   - query param PARAM_ALF_TICKET = "alf_ticket":

     ```
     url?alf_ticket=your-ticket
     ```
   - or header AUTHORIZATION_HEADER = "Authorization":

     ```
     Authorization: Basic base64_encode(user+":"+password)
     ```
2. [Copy Node REST API](https://wildloop.github.io/alfresco-rest-api-explorer-dev-demo/#!/nodes/copyNode) (available in Alfresco 5.2 and newer versions):

   ```
   curl -X POST 
   --header 'Content-Type: application/json' 
   --header 'Accept: application/json' 
   --header 'Authorization: Basic eW91LWFyZTp0aGUtYmVzdC1oYWNrZXI7KQ==' 
   -d '{
     "targetParentId": "new-parent-folder-node-id",
     "name": "new-node-name"
   }' 
   'http://localhost:8080/alfresco/api/-default-/public/alfresco/versions/1/nodes/{node-id}/copy'
   ```

Comment: Thank you so much sir @imagine

Answer (score 0):

Regarding web-service authentication it does not work with the alfresco for BASE64. Web-service authentication works in alfresco using alf_ticket.401 is error of unauthorization.

As far as i know , there is no web-service available for coping node in alfresco.You need to create your own webscript for same.For creating custom webscript below link will be use-full for you.

[Repository webscript in alfresco](http://www.krutikjayswal.com/2016/10/alfresco-webscript-spring-webscript.html)

Comment: but i use that Authorisation when i wanna destroy a session after a user disconnect from the my application , Also i don't have access to the alfresco back end so im stuck with the Api .Thank you for your response